# Backend JSON response

Tags: php, mysql, json, server

I have created a CMS and tested it in *localhost* and read all the json responses. However, when I put the code in a live server, I can still *insert*, *view* and *edit* data but I can't read any json responses. And this is a crusial part, as I need them for my android app.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
include ("../includes/connect.php");

$string = "";
$newString = "";
$get_posts = "select * from last_game";
$run_posts = mysqli_query($con, $get_posts);
$posts_array = array();

while ($posts_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts))
{
  $row_array['id'] = $posts_row['id'];
  $row_array['game'] = $posts_row['game'];
  $row_array['date'] = $posts_row['date'];
  array_push($posts_array, $row_array);
}

$string = json_encode($posts_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $string;
?>
```

There error I am getting is

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - assumed 
'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' in /var/www/vhosts/theo-
 android.co.uk/httpdocs/manudb/android/last_game_json.php on line 26

Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in    
/var/www/vhosts/theo-
android.co.uk/httpdocs/manudb/android/last_game_json.php on line 26
```

Could it be something wrong with the php version?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the errors you're getting... Check browser's developer console for JS errors or the server for PHP errors (if they're set not to be displayed)

Comment: Remove the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE constant

Comment: Yes!!! It is working now!:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your MySQL connection needs different credential on live server:
check your `connect.php` to be sure mysql host/user/password and db name are correct.

You can check what server response by manually point your browser to remote server and see what's happening, probably you should enable debugging with something like:
`error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

important: remember to remove those lines when going in production !

Comment: After putting the lines of code you suggested,I get this error.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' in /var/www/vhosts/theo-android.co.uk/httpdocs/manudb/android/last_game_json.php on line 26

Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /var/www/vhosts/theo-android.co.uk/httpdocs/manudb/android/last_game_json.php on line 26